# Confusion between negative and positive signs in natural logarithm

Tags: logarithms

If $z= - 0.1887\cdot(x^{0.7637})\cdot(y^{0.2306})$

Its natural logarithm will be

$\ln(z) = - [ \ln(0.1887) + 0.7637 \ln(x) + 0.2306 \ln(y)]$

or

$\ln(z) = - [ \ln(0.1887) - 0.7637 \ln(x) - 0.2306 \ln(y)]$?

Thank you in advance

Comment: neither of them

Comment: @Berci.. Thankyou!

Comment: Hint:  To write multidigit exponents, put them in braces.  So x^{0.7637} gives $x^{0.7637}$  To get functions in the right font, put a backslash first, so \ln gives $\ln$

Comment: @RossMillikan.. Done!! Thankyou.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an answer is required, maybe try
$$
\ln(z) = \ln(-1) + \ln(0.1887) + 0.7637 \ln(x) + 0.2306 \ln(y)
$$
As others stated, this is not a real number.  But maybe some complex number answer is intended?

Answer (score 1):

The logarithm *of a negative number* is **not defined** among real numbers. 
(It can have infinitely many values among complex numbers.)

But, for example  $x^A / \,y^B = A\ln x - B\ln y$ if you want subtraction, or
$(1/s)^A \cdot x^B\cdot y^C = -A\ln s+B\ln x+C\ln y\ $  if you like.

Comment: @Berci.. okay! Thanks.. Actually I have expression in this form only! I don't know how to find its natural log!!

Comment: Find the log of its absolute value but remember the sign.

Comment: @Berci..How? Can you suggest it for my Question.. My both answer seems to be incorrect..